# Can Ubuntu really run all Windows programs?

Tags: windows

I recently stumbled over the *Ubuntu for Tablets* video, where Mark Shuttleworth presents how Ubuntu is going to look on tablets.

However, he said one thing that struck me at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h384z7Ph0gU&t=5m15s. He said that **Ubuntu could run "all Windows apps"**.

How does this work? Was he talking about Wine (which definitely can't run *every* Windows program) or did he mean something else?

Comment: Many Windows-8 apps can be web-apps, which was the plan for Ubuntu-touch as well, maybe he's referring to easy porting of existing apps?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

He said: "all Windows apps as *a thin client*". Since "thin clients" usually involve program execution elsewhere, presumably this means via remote desktop or something similar. And the [Ubuntu for Android page](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android) mentions Citrix thin clients.

Answer (score 2):

And of course you can run a licensed version of Windows as a guest OS in a Virtual Machine using Ubuntu as the host (which I guess would sort of be cheating because you are running Windows and not Ubuntu ;). This will work with most Windows programs, but you can occasionally run into issues with application licensing that won't run in a VM and/or hardware requirements that can't be satisfied by the VM.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your question, *Wine definitely can't run every Windows program*. You can search for a particular Windows application at the [WineHQ](https://www.winehq.org/) website, and it will tell you whether that application is supported by Wine. If the Windows application is supported by Wine, WineHQ will also show a rating (Garbage/Bronze/Silver/Gold/Platinum) of how well that application runs on Wine.